# have a unique number in the url - do not match

Tags: .htaccess

This is how I would like to get my url to look at it any other way than before.

The problem is such that I must have forum and after forum content unique number that is in the database and after the url of the content.

I could imagine that it looked like this:

```
/forum/1/hello-world-stackoverflow-danmark/
```

now on my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/.]*)/([^/.]*)/?$ /forum-s.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

and now it:

```
www.hello-world.com/forum/velkommen-til-traenigsmakker---sjaelland/
```

I will have its to

```
www.hello-world.com/forum/1/velkommen-til-traenigsmakker---sjaelland/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to have RewriteEngine On

The code you have should work, you can optimize it like this to ensure the numbers.

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9]+)/([^/.]*)/?$ /forum-s.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L]
```